# VBA: Cumulative addition of data across columns for a set number of times

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to using Excel VBA and I have tried to solve this but can't for the life of me get my head around how to do it.

I have a set of data listed in column A and another set of data listed in Column E.
I would like to calculate and display the following addition of A2 and E2 in Column K. The number of times this would be done is determined by the value displayed in C2, i.e.:

```
A2 + E2
A2 + (E2*2)
A2 + (E2*3)
.
.
A2 + (E2*C2)
```

I then would like to display the cumulative addition of A3 and E3 in Column K+3 (three columns along), and A4+E3 in Column K+6, and so on. I would like to repeat this until all rows with numbers in Column A have been dealt with.

Here is an image of what the spreadsheet would look like with the first three columns of calculations filled in (please note a number of columns have been hidden):

Screenshot of spreadsheet with values calculated using formulae

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet with values calculated using formulae]

I hope this all makes sense.. And thank you ever so much for your help with this!

Comment: Why can't this be done with a formula? Have you tried anything? Can you show your original effort toward resolving this (working or not)? Do you expect everyone one of on the other side of this question to independently retype your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBA sub procedure on values in worksheet 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well @A.S.H, I tried to put the solution into their own vernacular. In a couple of days I will [edit] to include the code as a copy & paste but today I just wanted to reproduce the original effort shown.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thanks for taking the time to look at this. Sorry if I came across as making no effort; I only started learning VBA this week and this was my first post on stackoverflow so I didn't know what to include and how to form a post (clearly). I can assure you I did try for a number of hours to break this little chestnut.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for others to copy and use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TDatapoints()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Cells(2, "k").Resize(.Cells(2, "c").Value2, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row - 1)
            .Formula = "=index($a:$a, column(b:b), 1)+index($e:$e, column(b:b), 1)*(row(1:1)-1)"
            .Value = .Value2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```